# Python: How do I change the line colours in pandas line plot?

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

I have the following code which produces a line plot with Financial Years on the `X axis`, and Count on the `Y axis`. It is done with matplotlib, and uses a dataframe called `DF`.

How do I change the colours of the lines to my choosing? I have done some googling, but all the examples I come across, do not use examples of a dataframe, they are all line plots from an X and Y series.

Could anyone help? (I have removed the styling from the following code for brevity)

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
DF.plot(ax=ax)
```

The dataframe is like this:

```
Cars        A    B   C
2011/2012   270 186 NaN
2012/2013   306 369 396.0
2013/2014   375 369 315.0
2014/2015   745 397 237.0
2015/2016   427 409 171.0
2016/2017   403 448 213.0
2017/2018   461 563 NaN


Index: 7 entries, 2011/2012 to 2017/2018
Data columns (total 3 columns):
A                   7 non-null object
B                   7 non-null object
C                   5 non-null float64
dtypes: float64(1), object(2)
```

Answer (score 0):

You'd just set the color attribute to the color you want:

```
https://matplotlib.org/users/colors.html
```

Comment: I am confused. The example you sent does not use a Dataframe, which is what I am struggling to understand. It has multiple plots using '(th, np.cos(th)'. I do not understand what that is, and how I can do it with a dataframe :S